# Error installing nokogiri xmlParseDoc check failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

OS: 10.9.3
ruby version management: rbenv

I followed steps mentioned in

http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for brew 0.9. Have 0.9.5 installed. Getting following error log while installing.

Please help in fixing. Below is the log:

```
System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /Users/parag/.bundler/tmp/65816/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/libxml2/2.8.0)...
Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /Users/parag/.bundler/tmp/65816/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0/libxslt/1.1.26)...
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a couple different packages. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I am on OSX 10.9.3